Paint the number line from each prime number to its closer prime neighbor. What proportion of the positive number line is painted?
Paint the number line from each prime number to its closer prime neighbor; in the case of a tie, choose the lower neighbor.


What is the limiting proportion of the positive number line that is painted?

That is, what is the limit, as $n\to\infty$, of the proportion of the number line from $0$ to $n$ that is painted?
Here is what I have found:

If, instead, we have uniformly random real numbers in an interval, then as the number of random numbers approaches infinity, the limiting proportion is $7/18$ (this is the "Birds on a Wire" problem, which inspired this question).

I doubt if this question can be answered with the current knowledge of primes. We don't even know an upper bound on the gap between two consecutive primes; this question requires information about the gap between three consecutive primes.

On second thought, I think for primes too, it should converge to the same limit $7/18$ as in the birds on a wire problem. Give me some time to draft an answer.

Is the graph in your post the one for primes or the one of for the uniform distribution case?

@NilotpalSinha The graph is for primes.

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. Consider the numbers from $p_1$ to $p_n$. Divide each number by $p_n$ to get the sequence $\displaystyle \frac{2}{p_n}, \frac{3}{p_n}, \cdots, 1$. This sequence approaches uniformly distribution in $(0,1)$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence in the limiting case, the proportion of number line colored in the case for primes will converge to that of the uniform distribution case i.e. $\displaystyle  \frac{7}{18}$.
